# Randomização/Aleatorismo C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, random

Boas. Estou a tentar criar um snake game em c# e não faço a mínima ideia de como posso fazer aparecer uma fruta nova em um lugar aleatório quando a serpente pega alguma fruta.

Comment: possível duplicata de [Localização de algo desenhado numa Picture Box C#](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/85627/localiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-algo-desenhado-numa-picture-box-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usando um exemplo que a área do jogo é 100 x 100 unidades (pixels, cm, mm, qq coisa), pode ser criado facilmente usando o objecto [`Random`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Random random = new Random();
int positionX = random.Next(0, 100),
    positionY = random.Next(0, 100);
```

a fruta seria entao colocada em:

```
addFruit(positionX, positionY);
```

Agora, apenas terá de ter em conta se esse ponto aleatório coincide com algum objecto existente na area de jogo, em caso afirmativo, volte a achar uma nova posicao.

exemplo, usando o [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Como o objecto `Random` uso o tempo para gerar números aleatórios, é normal, se não for para tarefas muito importantes, usar um delay depois de ter sido gerado um número. Por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

usando uma simples paragem rápida, verifica-se que os números abrangem muito mais a totalidade dos limites.